# Product Classification

Tags: classification, product, analysis, simplification

This is my first post on Stackoverflow but I've consulted this website very often. I was hoping someone could help me out.

I'm trying to do a mapping of a product catalogue (not sure if it's the right term) in order to simplify it in the end. What I would like to achieve is to get a overview of the current product structure.

Variables:

- Product_Name: definition of the product, total of 27 unique products
- Product_Type: either data, voice, add-on or non-services
- Customer_segment: 6 distinct segments
- Carrier_type: how is the product delivered? (fiber/coax etc.)

Optional variables:

- Account_ID: customer number
- Revenue

What am I trying to achieve?
I would like to see how the columns relate to each other. So if I have for example product A, then I would like to see which options are related to this particular product.

```
                                        Product A

             Segment A                  Segment B                  Segment C

      Carrier A   Carrier B        Carrier A  Carrier C        Carrier B  Carrier D
```

I'm looking for ways on how to make such decision trees in R since I do not want to make these on my own. Even more awesome would be to include the account ID and revenue somehow. I've already looked into Market Basket Analysis but this only gives me the most common combinations of products per account (basket). Now I want to see which products belong together and to see if there is any overlap between them in order to simplify it in the end.

I'm not asking for a complete set of code but more like a push into the right direction. Does anyone know which method of analysis would be suited to do this?

Thanks!